# Translate a html attribute to javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$("div").click(function () {                
    var obj = { flammable: 'inflammable', duh: 'no duh' };
    $.each(obj, function (key, value) {
        alert(key + ": " + value);
    });
});
```

This works without problem and alerts key/value.

```
$("div").click(function () {                
    var obj = $(this).attr("obj");
    $.each(obj, function (key, value) {
        alert(key + ": " + value);
    });
});

<div obj="{ flammable: 'inflammable', duh: 'no duh' }">click</div>
```

However this is not working?

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
var obj = $(this).attr("obj");
```

to

```
var obj = JSON.parse($(this).attr("obj"));
```

Also, you may want to use escaped double quotes rather than single quotes inside the object, make it

```
<div obj="{ \"flammable\": \"inflammable\", \"duh\": \"no duh\" }">click</div>
```

or

```
<div obj= '{"name":"John Johnson","street":"Oslo West 16","phone":"555 1234567"}' >click</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I was thinking about json aswell, althoug I would prefer object syntax. However it did not seems to work.

Comment: @dbol can you please share a fiddle or stacksnippet (using an icon on top in the edit mode).

Comment: This one works: '{"name":"John Johnson","street":"Oslo West 16","phone":"555 1234567"}'

Comment: @dbol Not sure why it didn't work. But I have updated my answer to include your working solution as well.